# Serving rtmp on port 1935

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, rtmp

I've been trying to get ffmpeg to stream in rtmp but connection to port 1935 is always refused. I really don't know what else I can do to allow this connection.

Here is what specs I'm running.

- Ubuntu 18.04 (tried with 19.04) however same issue - here is why I think I've made a mistake
- No Nginx installation at the moment
- FFMPEG "ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)"

This is the script I run:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv "rtmp://127.0.0.1/stream/test"
```

Error I get is:

```
[tcp @ 0x55ff05ab8ce0] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:1935 failed: Connection refused
```

I've done some research and been across many posts about ffserver.conf and I have made those changes but still no luck. Here is my config file. I also have ran ffserver once using this config.

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 127.0.0.1
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

<Feed feed1.ffm>

File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200K

# Only allow connections from localhost to the feed.
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost     
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream test1.mpg>

# coming from live feed 'feed1'
Feed feed1.ffm

Format mpeg
AudioBitRate 32

# Number of audio channels: 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 44100

# Bitrate for the video stream
VideoBitRate 64

# Ratecontrol buffer size
VideoBufferSize 40

# Number of frames per second
VideoFrameRate 3


</Stream>


<Stream test.asf>
Feed feed1.ffm
Format asf
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoSize 352x240
VideoBitRate 256
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 30
AudioBitRate 64
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>

# Special streams

# Server status

<Stream stat.html>
Format status

ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255

#FaviconURL http://pond1.gladstonefamily.net:8080/favicon.ico
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

Here is my ufw status:

```
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
1935/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1935/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

but still nothing, I've also opened ports in iptables but no luck. Here is how this is done:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT

and

iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
```

and still nothing, every time I run ffmpeg I get connection refused. I have previously installed nginx just to test but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't this port suppose to be open now?

Thanks

Comment: What ar you trying to connect to? How are you running the server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using Nginx RTMP module - Nginx RTMP for some reason doesn't work well on Ubuntu but fine with Alpine 3.8 - As soon as I started a nginx rtmp docker container and exposed 1935 and 80 everything started working fine. Listen learnt, never install nginx rtmp module on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

@JJ-the-Second, I have been using nginx rtmp module on ubuntu natively and it is working completely fine. But instead of sending stream to `127.0.0.1`, I either send it to `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: thanks for confirming. I think if you know what you doing and is not your first rounds of trial and error then there shouldn't be an issue on any linux flavours. Isolating that and making it work indicates to me that it was my security or port issue, solution worked for me and what you say is 100% correct.